# How to implement Eclipse-style search in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, where-clause

I have a table that contains full names (first middle last) and i want to search for persons by  `first+last` using Sqlite where clause

i.e. if the full name is: `John Michel William` i want to get it if i search by `John William`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `like` clause :

```
...
where NAME like 'John%William'
```

Another solution is to use a [FTS](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) table, in which case you can use `MATCH` queries :

```
....
where NAME match 'John William'
```

(this will also retrieve `XXXX John William` or even `William John` which is probably not what you want in this case)